# How to format currency in the templates?

Tags: templates

Is there a native way to do this? Or must I use an add-on like: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/price-format?

Comment: I usually use the addon you mentioned along with the [Dollars](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dollars-fieldtype) addon to try and reduce the likelihood of admins entering price data in an unexpected format. Otherwise, yeah BR & Store do this stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the Dollars FT. I think I might use it. I don't think it handles this format, though: `$1 350,50` (e.g. French format), but it's better than using the text FT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no native EE way to do it.

If you're using an e-commerce add-on like Store there are built in methods to format currency.

Otherwise, that add-on looks like it will do exactly what you need.

Comment: what do you do with the file once you've downloaded it? The add-on isn't very descriptive.

(pi.price_format.php)

Comment: Upload to `system/expressionengine/third_party/price_format/pi.price_format.php` on your server, then it will be already installed. It's the same process for all plugins which is probably why there aren't any instructions.